# Using Ansible to generate a random password with very specific properties

Tags: security, ansible, passwords

I have the following code which perfectly generates me a passwords of length between 20 and 25 with the characters I want. However I noticed that sometimes same characters are repeated next to each other.

Is there a way or code I could use so that characters do not get repeated within the password generated?

```yaml
--- #This is how a yml file starts

- set_fact:
    size: 
      - "{{20 + (5 | random )}}"

- debug:
    var: size

- name: create a passowrd of length "{{ size }}"
  set_fact:
    random_password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length={{ size | random }} chars=ascii_lowercase,ascii_uppercase,digits,_-!.,;:') }}"
    

- name: Debug to show password created above
  debug:
    msg: "{{random_password}}"
```

I am not too sure what to do for this part.

Comment: Hi Ziad welcome to SO. I would guess `until: random_password is not match('.*(.)\\1.*')` since the `match` test honors `re.search` syntax and it allows immediate backrefs to identify concurrent characters

Answer (score 0):

> *... sometimes same characters are repeated next to each other. Is there a way or code I could use so that characters do not get repeated within the password generated?*

A minimal example

**`task.yml`**

```yaml
---
- name: Create a password
  set_fact:
    random_password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length={{ 20 + (5 | random) | int }} chars=ascii_lowercase,ascii_uppercase,digits,_-!.,;:') }}"
```

**`playbook.yml`**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Generate a random_password
    include: task.yml
    until:  random_password is not match('.*(.)\\1.*')

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ random_password }}"
```

could result into the output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: tN.NsnTmm6:NInnbd6Fe4
```

As well a minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Create a password
    set_fact:
      random_password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length={{ 20 + (5 | random) | int }} chars=ascii_lowercase,ascii_uppercase,digits,_-!.,;:') }}"
    until:  random_password is not match('.*(.)\\1.*') 
    retries: 10
```

could result into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (10 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (9 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (8 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (7 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (6 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (5 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Create a password (1 retries left).

TASK [Create a password] ******************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    random_password: 'J2LLMsf5CKFOvg8x3S8rub:'
  attempts: 10
```

It will probably take the first generated and will not become updated afterwards. This is because of the nature of Ansible, how variables becomes registered and how tasks become compiled and executed.

To resolve the behavior it would be necessary to put the `lookup` into the `until` which then prevents it from `register`ing.

---

> *Is there a way ... I could use ...*

Since [Ansible isn't a coding language](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-coding-programming) and if your Use Case is to generate random strings with such specific properties it seems to be recommended to write a small script or Custom Module which does the task and provide just the required result which can than become registered. Starting points for further research could be

- [Does a password policy with a restriction of repeated characters increase security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/269996/167452)
- [Creating a random string in Python without duplicating characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18705796/6771046)